# Cancelling a single Task or Particular Tasks in Parallel.ForEach in c#

Tags: c#, task, parallel.foreach

i have a requirement where we are running some tasks using Parallel.ForEach . at a time the user can decide to cancel any of the Tasks or a single Task from the TaskList provided to Parallel.ForEach.
i have tried with CancellationToken but it fires for all the Tasks  in the TaskList . i have also tried ParallelLoopState but even that is not able to do what i am looking for.

I worked on this POC using the below code and I could not make it working.

The bottleneck is in the below statement

```
Parallel.ForEach(nums, new ParallelOptions() { CancellationToken = new CancellationToken() } , (num) =>
```

Since we have to pass the Cancellation Token in the Foreach , I am not able to pass an individual Cancellation Token for each item in Foreach Loop.

I don’t want to go for that Task approach as there is overhead involved in Task versus Parallel.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] nums = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).ToArray();
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        // Use ParallelOptions instance to store the CancellationToken
        ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
        po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;
        po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start. Press 'c' to cancel.");
        Console.ReadKey();

        // Run a task so that we can cancel from another thread.
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'c')
                cts.Cancel();

            Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit");
        });

        try
        {   
            Parallel.ForEach(nums, new ParallelOptions() { CancellationToken = new CancellationToken() } , (num) =>
            {
                double d = Math.Sqrt(num);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} on {1}", d, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            });
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cts.Dispose();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: instead of Parallel.For you can use foreach item in items: `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `Task.Run` then you can cancel individual tasks.

Comment: Can you add more about the overhead with Task?

Comment: I don't understand this part of your question: "[at any time] the user can decide to cancel any of the Tasks or a single Task from the TaskList provided to Parallel.ForEach" - how does the user decide which task to cancel? Your example just has a single cancellation token.

Comment: The tasks are almost 82. each TAsk runs from 20 secs to 20mins . each task has a testname. we want the user to provide us with a TestName and we should be able to cancel that task

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to create separate cancellation tokens for each task (or group of tasks, whatever the criteria is). You can explicitly call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` on the appropriate token before doing the expensive part of the task.

```
// Assume the nums.length == tokens.length
int[] nums = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).ToArray();
CancellationToken[] tokens = ...

try
{
    Parallel.ForEach(nums, (num) =>
    {
        tokens[num].ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        double d = Math.Sqrt(num);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} on {1}", d, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);        
    });
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
    // One or more tasks was canceled or threw an exception.
    // e.InnerExceptions contains the individual OperationCanceledException
    // or other exceptions that were thrown.
}
```

Note the difference between checking a token in a task vs. supplying a token to `Parallel.ForEach`. Canceling the entire `Parallel.ForEach` should avoid running any tasks that have not started and throw a single OperationCanceledException.

```
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;
// ...

try
{
    Parallel.ForEach(nums, po, (num) => { ... });
}
catch (OperationCanceledException e)
{
    // The entire operation was cancelled.
}
```

Comment: i like your solution, but its a little bit vulnerable against changes from the outside. Imho we should always try to pass a state object (like a token) INTO the Task. Currently you're accessing an outside mutable collection object `tokens` from inside your tasks. What if the tokens[] gets modified or set to null

Comment: I guess you could use an immutable collection of tokens. It really depends on your requirements. You don't need to allocate a token per task up front - that's actually rather expensive. You could have some other logic for checking cancellation and throwing an `OperationCanceledException` explicitly.